# getting url to work with or without  a subexpression  

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

im trying to rewrite a url like

page.php?sort=66&search=s&category=2,3,4&archive=june&page=3

to

page-sort-1-search(s)-category-1,2,3-archive(june)-page3

but the thing is each of this subexpressions my or may not be in the url every time that this page is called so i had to put each one in the "( )?" so the regex works with or without them

```
^page
(-sort-([0-9]*))?     
(-search\(([a-z]*)\))? 
(-category-([0-9][,]?*))?
```

.............
you get the idea

now the problem is mode rewrite is considering each one of this subexpression in the parenthesis as an actual variable

```
(-sort-([0-9]*))?  this is how mode rewrite interpret this  => $1 = -sort-66  ,  $2 = 66
```

so for each subexpression i got 2 capture-group and that's more then 10 for a link with 5-6 variable
and there is a 9 match limit in mode rewrite

is there a replacement for "()?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to admit, I'm a bit confused by some parts of your question, so I apologize in advance if my answer is totally off-base . . . but it *sounds* like what you need is a non-capturing group. This:

```
(...)
```

matches `...` and creates a capture-group (what you're calling a "variable"); this:

```
(?:...)
```

*just* matches `...`, without creating a capture-group. So it's useful if all you want to do is group a subexpression, without saving all of its contents to be used as `$1`.

Comment: thanx but when i use (?:subexp) , url doesn't work without that particular subexpression , what i want is that url works with or without that subexpression , is there a  way to do that or should i write a regex for each possible situation ?

Comment: @max: Sorry, I think you misunderstood me. I wasn't suggesting that you change `(...)?` to `(?:...)`. I was suggesting that you change `(...)` to `(?:...)` -- that is, that you change `(...)?` to `(?:...)?`. For the subexpression to be optional, you still need the question-mark after it. Does that make sense?